# angular material: missing binding for cypress attribute data-cy

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress

I want to use some angular material components in my angular app. I want to test ist with cypress.io. As suggested by cypress data-cy (or data-test) attribute should be used for better selection purposes. The problem is when I use it with angular material componentes following error occurs:
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

> Can't bind to 'test' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-row'.
>   1. If 'mat-row' is an Angular component and it has 'test' input, then verify >that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'mat-row' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the >'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of >this component. ("

With the example below there is the problem with mat-row and using data-test

```
<mat-row data-test="{{row.id}}" *matRowDef="let row; columns: attributDefColumns;" (click)="detailsClicked(row.id)"></mat-row>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - adding Cypress data-cy attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453410/angular-adding-cypress-data-cy-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<mat-row [attr.data-test]="{{row.id}}" 
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: attributDefColumns;" 
    (click)="detailsClicked(row.id)">
</mat-row>
```